# How to get the type of the unary operator '-' in haskell

Tags: haskell

In haskell, negative numbers come from using the unary operator `'-'` in front of a number, but the subtraction function also use `'-'`. So when you type `:t (-)` in ghci, you only get the result of the subtraction function's type like

```
:t (-)
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

But is it possible to get the type of the "negate operator" in ghci? I know this is trivial, but I am curious.

Comment: The unary operator `-` isn't really an operator at all, it's actually a completely special case: syntactic sugar for `negate`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, I am aware of that. I am just refering to that generically because it is a non-alphabetic symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could eta expand it:

```
Prelude> :t \x -> -x
\x -> -x :: Num a => a -> a
```